# Access a custom object that resides in plug in dll

Tags: c#, dll

I have a standalone application that exports some data from a database.  In this program I have a custom object, ExportParams, that keeps the database information, server, database name etc, that can come from the user interface, a config file or from the command prompt.  I now need to change this standalone application into a plugin.  The user interface I have converted into a plugin and can run without issue.  The issue I am having is how do I access this custom object from the main form so I can send in the parameters from the command prompt or config file into the plugin?

Comment: Is it in the same namespace?  Have you added a reference to it in the project containing the main form?

Comment: Different namespace and I have had the main form referenced in the dll.

Comment: Make reference to the dll in the main form not the other way I think

Comment: But if the plugin dll is not present, I think the program will not run.  This would defeat the purpose of a plugin.

Comment: But when you application is compiled then the dll will be included?   I am not sure what you mean by a plugin.  Is this supposed to fit into a plugin architecture used by the main app or is it just a library dll containing certain functions?

Comment: Fit into a plugin architecture used by the main app

Comment: Then the plugin architecture must have some way to find plugins and make them available to your main app.  Is that what you are asking for a plugin architecture = have you researched for one?

Comment: I have looked around and I can find how to get to the functions in the plugin but not to the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create an interface in a separate project and implement the interface in the ExportParams object. Then reference the interface in both projects and pass around an instance of the interface.

Comment: That is the road I started down but then I have three files, main.exe, comm.dll and plugin.dll that I will have to move around and I would like to keep it at two files, main.exe nd plugin.dll

Comment: Well you either have an interface as I suggest, or rely on reflection and then invoking a known method on the object using know method names strings (yuck) and parameters. Alternatively, and I really don't recomend this, put the interface in the exe and let the plugin reference the exe. This way you get your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like answering a question with a series of links.  However I think you need to research plugin architectures.  There are a lot of questions here already on Stack Overflow plus there are lots of articles and blog posts on plugins.  I use a plugin architecture and I have a plugin interface.  That interface defines both the methods and properties that the plugin has to support.

I offer some links for you to try:

http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/implementing-a-plug-in-architecture-in-c/184403942

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FArticles%2F4691%2FPlugin-Architecture-using-C&ei=S58QU4TmMYTChAfjsICgAw&usg=AFQjCNFb9oIQhGFFS80j-VImzXGlH9k1-Q&sig2=jyO0ebkv8oG4MJwKgwF_ww&bvm=bv.61965928,d.ZG4

Here on Stack Overflow

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F829597%2Fc-sharp-plugin-architecture-with-interfaces-share-between-plugins&ei=S58QU4TmMYTChAfjsICgAw&usg=AFQjCNG0nWoQPlqA6hqpLvscG3wXI4oc8A&sig2=SYrtvoDlA7yD3eypY8jKuw&bvm=bv.61965928,d.ZG4

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4748007%2Fc-sharp-dlls-plugin-architecture&ei=S58QU4TmMYTChAfjsICgAw&usg=AFQjCNFXXxla7VqUWYcFS1QXmfkboKUJ6g&sig2=BIFpdFTwGGD0BsqjK-RcCA&bvm=bv.61965928,d.ZG4

I hope this helps a bit

Comment: Thanks, I will look thru.  I have been able to find a lot of examples of getting the methods but not the objects.